# How to get the position after drop with cdkDrag?

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, draggable

Hi I need to be able to drag and drop some html elements but I need to know the end position of the drop.

using the `cdkDrag` directive I see from the [docs](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/api) that there's an event `cdkDragEnded`.

This is my template:

```
<div cdkDrop>
  <div cdkDrag (cdkDragEnded)="dragEnd($event)">
    ...other stuff
  </div>
</div>
```

The callback is:

```
dragEnd(event: CdkDragEnd) {
  console.log(event);
}
```

In the console I found what I need but it is a private property of the event `event.source._dragRef._passiveTransform` and I get the error message when I compile.

Do you know if such data or something else that I can use is exposed somehow?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Simply use `source.getFreeDragPosition()` in `(getFreeDragPosition)` event like this:

```js
dragEnd($event: CdkDragEnd) {
    console.log($event.source.getFreeDragPosition());
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Also note that you later can restore the position using [cdkDragFreeDragPosition]="dragPosition"

Comment: Simple code but solves the problem the most correct way.

Comment: Brilliant answer!

Answer (score 7):

The solution I found is to retrieve the `style.transform` value that `cdkDrag` set

```js
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from "@angular/core";
import { CdkDragEnd } from "@angular/cdk/drag-drop";

@Component({
  selector: "item",
  styles: [
    `
      .viewport {
        position: relative;
        background: #ccc;
        display: block;
        margin: auto;
      }
      .item {
        position: absolute;
        background: #aaa;
      }
    `
  ],
  template: `
    <div class="viewport" cdkDrop>
      <div
        #item
        class="item"
        cdkDrag
        (cdkDragEnded)="dragEnd($event)"
        [style.top.px]="initialPosition.y"
        [style.left.px]="initialPosition.x"
      >
        anything
      </div>
    </div>
  `
})
export class CanvasItemComponent {
  constructor() {}

  @ViewChild("item")
  item: ElementRef;

  initialPosition = { x: 100, y: 100 };
  position = { ...this.initialPosition };
  offset = { x: 0, y: 0 };

  dragEnd(event: CdkDragEnd) {
    const transform = this.item.nativeElement.style.transform;
    let regex = /translate3d\(\s?(?<x>[-]?\d*)px,\s?(?<y>[-]?\d*)px,\s?(?<z>[-]?\d*)px\)/;
    var values = regex.exec(transform);
    console.log(transform);
    this.offset = { x: parseInt(values[1]), y: parseInt(values[2]) };

    this.position.x = this.initialPosition.x + this.offset.x;
    this.position.y = this.initialPosition.y + this.offset.y;

    console.log(this.position, this.initialPosition, this.offset);
  }
}
```

or:

```js
dragEnd(event: CdkDragEnd) {
    this.offset = { ...(<any>event.source._dragRef)._passiveTransform };

    this.position.x = this.initialPosition.x + this.offset.x;
    this.position.y = this.initialPosition.y + this.offset.y;

    console.log(this.position, this.initialPosition, this.offset);
  }
```

Is there a better way to get that transform x and y values without using private variables?

**Edit:**
The feature will be added in https://github.com/angular/material2/pull/14696

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to figure out is happening. I can see that there is an initialposition that doesn't get altered, but is used set the elements placement. However, on dragend the position is being calculated but it is not updating initialposition (which is being used for the slide). I tried to update the initialPosition and found that the element was jumping around, so I'm not sure what is happening.

Answer (score 4):

Another solution I'm using to get the Dragged item's position *after the drop* is:

**Template**

```html
<div
  cdkDrag
  (cdkDragEnded)="dragEnded($event)"
>
</div>
```

**Component**

```js
  dragEnded($event: CdkDragEnd) {
    const { offsetLeft, offsetTop } = $event.source.element.nativeElement;
    const { x, y } = $event.distance;
    this.positionX = offsetLeft + x;
    this.positionY = offsetTop + y;
    this.showPopup = true;
    console.log({ positionX, positionY });
  }
```

**Setting Position**

There's cases where you might want to display something when the drag finishes.

```html
<div
  *ngIf="showPopup"
  [ngStyle]="{
    'left': positionX + 'px',
    'right': positionY + 'px'
  }"
>
  I'm in position!
</div>
```

Comment: I need to try this, I don't think that it much different than using `_passiveTransform`, at least `distance` was meant to be _public_

Comment: How did you set the position after this?